# Get value from array

Tags: php, arrays

how can I echo the 33 form this printed array directly?

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [max(renr)] => 333 ) )`

Thanks

Comment: Do you use PHP? comes the data from a database or json?

Comment: Yes.I do. It is a normal SQL Database with a max() statement.

Comment: use an alias in SQL: SELECT MAX(foo) AS max FROM .... then you can access it: $arr[0]->max

Answer (score 3):

`$array[0]->{'max(renr)'}`

Comment: You can use the curly braces to access the value in the object.

Comment: You really should use aliases in your SQL.  `SELECT max(renr) AS renrMax`

Comment: Yes.. PLEASE use aliases. Your PHP code will make everyone reading it hate you if you go with the `->{'max(rend)'}` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's gonna depend on your language, but assuming PHP from the look of it...

```
$arr[0]->max(renr)
```

But to be far, I don't know what an index of max(renr) means

Comment: This is does not work. The max(x) ist the sql max() function. Maybe that helps.

Comment: `$arr[0]->{'max(renr)'}`  You need the curly braces to access the value because of the parentheses.

Comment: @jon_darkstar: This is the syntax for a method call, and will yield a "Call to undefined method stdClass::max" fatal error.

Comment: how does an echo_r/var_dump give the value of a method call like that?  a method call, for a variable argument?  thats what threw me.  never thought it was SQL, would've given that bracket syntax if i knew what as going on

Comment: o nevermind get it.  'max(renr)' is literally the index bc thats how it let it come back from sql right?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` for array and `->` for objects

Answer (score 0):

Use an alias in your SQL query so you have an alphanumeric column name in the result set. That's the only real solution.

```
SELECT MAX(renr) AS max_renr FROM ....
```

and then `$arr[0]->max_renr` in your php code.